# Jquery mobile+ i need to modify the radio button. how can i show text left side and icon right side for arebic?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I need to modify the **radio buttons**. how can i show text left side and icon right side for Arabic text?

Comment: You **need** to show us what you have tried and expand your question to more than "do this for me please." Notice your other questions have gotten very little attention, this is because of your one-line questions that simply ask for something to be done for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just render a radiobutton like you want it:

```
<input type="radio" name="something"/>
<label>Radio Right</label>
```

or

```
 <label>Radio Left</label>
 <input type="radio" name="something2"/>
```

​